# Use liferay-ui:message tag in template freemarker

Tags: localization, liferay, freemarker, liferay-theme

I am a newbie in Liferay 7. I created a navbar in my site. I need to set the labels in my navbar e.g. "Name" in japanese. In jsp, liferay-ui:message is avaialable to get the value of the labels. So I added this tags in my init.ftl file.

```
 <#assign liferay_ui = taglibLiferayHash["/WEB-INF/tld/liferay-ui.tld"] />
```

However, I am having an error below.

```
 freemarker.template.TemplateModelException: Error while loading tag library for URI "/WEB-INF/tld/liferay-ui.tld" from TLD location "servletContext:/WEB-INF/tld/liferay-ui.tld"; see cause exception. FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):
- Failed at: #assign liferay_ui = taglibLiferayHas...  [in template "vsp-theme_SERVLET_CONTEXT_/templates/init.ftl" at line 333, column 2]
```

Comment: "However, I am having an error below" followed by a code-formatted URL to an unrelated blogpost - You might want to post the error message instead, please edit your question.

Comment: Hi Olaf! didn't notice I pasted a wrong link. Edited the my question above. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try this:

```
<#assign msg = languageUtil.get(locale, "my-custom-message-blah-blah") />
```

Answer (score 0):

Taglib not required, just us below tags.

```
<@liferay_ui["message"] key="popular" />
```

or

```
<@liferay.language key="next" />
```